# Pass action with model to jquery ajax success call

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor

My Jquery Ajax Call. How to return model from action to ajax and pass to another action.

```
    function ChangeName(id)
        {
        var name=$("#name").val();
          $.ajax({
                   cache:false,
                   url: "@Url.Action("EditName", "Order")",
                   data: "Name=" +name+"&Id="+id ,
                   type: "POST",
                   success: function (data) {
                     window.location.href=data.Url;//doesnt work passes null model

                                             }
                                             });
        }


    public ActionResult EditName(string name,int id)
    {
        var product= GetProduct(id);
        product.Name=name;
        UpdateProduct(product);

        var model=new ProdModel(){id=id};
        return Json(new
        {
            Url = Url.Action("Test","Order",new{model=model})
        },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }



 public ActionResult Test(ProdModel model)//Model null
        {

           return RedirectToAction("List", "Product");
        }
```

I have tried this but not getting success.

Comment: Your're passing `ProdModel` when `Test` action is expecting `OrderModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function ChangeName(id)
    {
    var name=$("#name").val();
    var params = {
        Name: name,
        Id: id
    };
      $.ajax({
               cache:false,
               url: '@Url.Action("EditName", "Order")',
               data: JSON.stringify(params),
               type: "POST",
               success: function (data) {
                 window.location.href=data.Url;//doesnt work passes null model
               }
       });
    }


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditName(string name,int id)
{
    var product= GetProduct(id);
    product.Name=name;
    UpdateProduct(product);

    var model=new ProdModel(){id=id};
    return Json(new
    {
        Url = Url.Action("Test","Order",new{model=product})
    },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: No I want to pass model in success call of jqery ajax

Comment: there is no problem with calling changename method , I have returned url in json data with model as parameter. Now on success I want to call other method with that model as parameter , which in my case going null

Comment: @Nitinvarpe if your first define question problem has been resolved then ask another question, because it is helpful to other users.

Comment: Dear @amit actually you didnt get my question problem wasnt with passing model to action but calling another action on success of ajax call, Please go through my code and see where error occurs

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

In `Edit Action` try returning the model instead of url,

```
    public josnResult EditName(string name,int id)
{
    var product= GetProduct(id);
    product.Name=name;
    UpdateProduct(product);

    var model=new ProdModel(){id=id};
    return Json(model,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then in ajax Success call you can make another call to `Test Action`

```
  $.ajax({
           cache:false,
           url: '@Url.Action("EditName", "Order")',
           data: JSON.stringify(params),
           type: "POST",
           success: function (data) {
             CallTestAction(data);
           }
   });
```

```
var CallTestAction = function(data) {
      $.ajax({
               cache:false,
               url: '@Url.Action("Test", "Order")',
               data: {model = data},
               type: "POST",
               success: function (data) {
               }
       });
};
```